# How to handle cq component with same html structure and different css?

Tags: css, jsp, adobe, aem

I have 2 jsps for 2 cq components that have the same html structure but the css is different.

- What are the best practices for refactoring in this case?

One scenario would be to have a single component and set the css classes based on some input provided by the author in the dialog (component type 1, component type 2), but this gets messy cause I need to do the if checks and set different values for the css classes. It becomes even more complicated if I add a 3rd component with the same html structure and different css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to use one of next approaches:

- Create base component with html structure and for each design create components which have `sling:resourceSuperType` of base component. And in child components you can override css file with specific one.
  **Base component** should be made of (at least) 2 jsp files:

  - container with some class (unique among different designs) which contains include of actual component content. This class then should be used in you selectors in css file. Like `.container-design-1 .title {}`. This container also can be overwritten in child components.
  - jsp with content.
- Also you can still use component dialogue, but populate dropdown menu with available designs dynamically. For example, you can have some servlet+service which looks into repository and collects available  clientlib categories for this component. And during rendering you will include selected clientlib category, set unique class for your container and use it in css selectors (like in previous approach).

Also in both cases html and id/class names of elements should be the same, and only styles implementation is different.

Comment: What if you can have both components on the same page? The CSS gets overridden then, right?

Comment: @GabrielaVisinari Ok, you are right. Updated answer.